# Dynamic components React

Tags: reactjs

I'm having an issue with dynamic components in React. Here is my code:

Comp1.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
export default class Comp1 extends React.Component {
    // ....
}
```

Parent.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import Comp1 from './components/Comp1.jsx';

const ConfigComponents = {
    comp1: Comp1
};

export const ConfigComponent = (props) => {
    let Component = ConfigComponents[ props.type ];

    return (
        <Component { ...props} />
    );
}

export default class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            componentToAdd: 'comp1'
        }
    }

    render() {
         return (
           <div>
             <ConfigComponent type={this.state.componentToAdd} />
           </div>
         )
    }
}
```

I have the following error:

```
React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

Looking on sof and Internet, it seems I've used the appropriate syntax (without {} for the import), so I don't understand what I'm missing. I followed this post: https://medium.com/@j5bot/react-dynamically-rendering-different-components-without-switch-the-capitalized-reference-e668d89e460b

Comment: Your `Parent`'s `render` method is missing a `return` statement.

Comment: Typo at `<ConfigComponent type={this.state.stateToAdd} />`

Comment: Those are typo when I wrote my question. It's ok in my code

Comment: I believe the issue lies with how you called Comp1.
When you write  :

return (<Component { ...props} />);

I recommend you tinker with different syntax and maybe directly with React.CreateElement to find out what was wrong.

Comment: what's the `react` version?

Comment: Got the exact same error with return (
        React.createElement(Component, props)
    );

Comment: "react": "^15.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"

Answer (score 0):

2 things.

1. Your `Parent`'s render method doesn't have a `return` statement.
2. You're passing `componentToAdd` instead of `stateToAdd` to `ConfigComponent`.

Fix your `Parent` component to

```js
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stateToAdd: "comp1"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ConfigComponent type={this.state.stateToAdd} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit strange-meadow-gn3p6]

Comment: Those are typo, I did not provide the real code and names. I've edited my question. The error is not due to this...

Comment: Maybe something's wrong with the `Comp1` component? A codesandbox with the error your describing would be helpful.

Comment: The following code works : {COMPONENT_CONFIG[this.state.componentToAdd]} with export const COMPONENT_CONFIG = {
    comp1: (
        <Comp1/>
    )
}